# Questions on: $g(f(x))=m(f(x))\implies g=m$ & $a(b(x))=a(c(x))\implies b=c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

> **Question:** Are either of the below statements true?

**First equivalency:** $g(f(x))=m(f(x))\implies g=m$

**Second equivalency:**  $a(b(x))=a(c(x))\implies b=c$

---

I believe that the first is true, but the second you could have $a(x)=0$ and thus this isn't true. I was just thinking about this when working with some functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, consider functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

First: take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ and $m(x)=|x|$.

Second: take $a(x)=x^2$ and $b(x)=x$ and $c(x)=-x$.  Or $a(x)=0$ as you suggested.

Neither implication is true.

**Addendum**: answer to question in comments.

Consider functions from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$ given by $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=\lfloor x/2\rfloor$ and $m(x)=\lfloor(x+1)/2\rfloor$.  Then $g(f(x))=m(f(x))=x$ but $g\ne m$.

The problem is that $g\circ f={\rm id}$ does not mean that $g=f^{-1}$.  If you take it one step further and assume that
$$g(f(x))=m(f(x))=\text{identity}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  f(g(x))=f(m(x))=\text{identity}\ ,$$
then it follows that $g=m$.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but such is life some times. Thank you :). Good answer

Comment: One further question. What if $g(f(x))=m(f(x))=\text{identity}$, e.g. both $g$ and $m$ are the inverse of $f$, then is $g=m$. Which I suppose is equivalent to is there only one inverse to a function, which sounds intuitively true. Or I suppose not(second edit), $f(x)=x, m(x)=1, g(x)=\frac1x$

Comment: @CareBear see updated answer.  The example in your comment is also good.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample.

Let $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational and 0 elsewhere. Let both $g$ and $m$ are equal to 0 on irrational arguments, but on the rational ones the first is equal to $x$ and the second to $2x$.

A counterexample to the second statement is very similar.